# Backup MySQL database with OHO Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3, database-backups

i have a problem to determine the destination where the zip backup file should be downloaded, and the name of the zip file are always generated randomly like this one i got **0ca26f32-b90c-4198-b078-ed2778a23c0b.zip** but the **sql** file inside the zipped folder is taking the given name **backup_2019-01-24-22-33-03.sql**

**PHP backup function**

The below function is downloading a zipped folder contains the database sql file in the default download folder in windows.

```
public function backup_get(){
        $prefs = array(
            'tables' => array('convt', 'invoice', 'item', 'order_inv', 'person', 'return_details'), // Array of tables to backup.
            'ignore' => array(), // List of tables to omit from the backup
            'format' => 'zip', // gzip, zip, txt
            'filename' => 'backup_' . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.sql', // File name - NEEDED ONLY WITH ZIP FILES
            'add_drop' => true, // Whether to add DROP TABLE statements to backup file
            'add_insert' => true, // Whether to add INSERT data to backup file
            'newline' => "\n", // Newline character used in backup file
        );

        $backup = $this->dbutil->backup($prefs);
        $db_name = 'backup-on-' . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.zip';
        $save = './backup/' . $db_name;
        $this->load->helper('file');
        write_file($save, $backup);


        http_response_code(200);
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($save));
        header("Content-Type: application/zip");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="backup.zip"');
        readfile($save);
        exit;
    }
```

**Problem**

i want to change the default destination form `downloads` folder to a one i manually/auto generated, and be able to give a name to the zip file.

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to modify the `backup_get()` function like this :

```
public function backup_get(){
    $prefs = array(
        'tables' => array('convt', 'invoice', 'item', 'order_inv', 'person', 'return_details'), // Array of tables to backup.
        'ignore' => array(), // List of tables to omit from the backup
        'format' => 'zip', // gzip, zip, txt
        'filename' => 'backup_' . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.sql', // File name - NEEDED ONLY WITH ZIP FILES
        'add_drop' => true, // Whether to add DROP TABLE statements to backup file
        'add_insert' => true, // Whether to add INSERT data to backup file
        'newline' => "\n", // Newline character used in backup file
    );

    $backup = $this->dbutil->backup($prefs);
    $db_name = 'backup-on-' . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.zip';
    $backup_path = './backup/'; // this is the destination directory name
    if (!file_exists($backup_path)) {
        mkdir($backup_path, 0755, true);
    }
    $save = $backup_path . $db_name;
    $this->load->helper('file');
    write_file($save, $backup);
}
```

The `$backup_path` is the custom directory that you want to set.

Answer (score 0):

Simple working code

```html
function database_backup()
{
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $prefs = array('format' => 'zip', 'filename' => 'Database-backup_' . date('Y-m-d_H-i'));
    $backup = $this->dbutil->backup($prefs);
    if (!write_file('./uploads/backup/BD-backup_' . date('Y-m-d_H-i') . '.zip', $backup)) {
    echo "Error while creating auto database backup!";
    }
    else {
            echo "Database backup has been successfully Created";
    }
}
```